# MySQL not selecting row if foreign key column has NULL value

Tags: mysql

The following SQL works, but if a row has `transfers.driver` as `NULL`, that row won't be selected. Once I add a value in for `driver` that row will be selected. How can I select the row even if `driver` is `NULL`?

```
SELECT 
    transfers.id, 
    transfers.name AS name, 
    transfers.pickup_time AS pickup_time, 
    transfers.voucher AS voucher, 
    transfer_types.name AS type, 
    drivers.name AS driver 
FROM
    transfers 
INNER JOIN transfer_types ON transfer_types.id = transfers.type 
INNER JOIN drivers ON drivers.id = transfers.driver
```

Here's the structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `transfers` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `voucher` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `pickup_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `driver` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And here's the foreign keys:

```
ALTER TABLE `transfers`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `transfers_driver_foreign` 
      FOREIGN KEY (`driver`) REFERENCES `drivers` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `transfers_type_foreign` 
      FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES `transfer_types` (`id`);
```

Comment: See [MySQL Join Made Easy For Beginners](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)

Answer (score 3):

use `left join` instead of `inner join`:

```
SELECT 
    transfers.id, 
    transfers.name AS name, 
    transfers.pickup_time AS pickup_time, 
    transfers.voucher AS voucher, 
    transfer_types.name AS type, 
    drivers.name AS driver 
FROM
    transfers 
LEFT JOIN transfer_types ON transfer_types.id = transfers.type 
LEFT JOIN drivers ON drivers.id = transfers.driver
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply. That worked perfect! I was actually reading about left joins right as you replied. I obviously have more to learn.